# oracle strange behavior on coping a table

Tags: oracle, partitioning

In currently trying to understand table partition in oracle and its impact on the performance. So i have a normal table CLIENTS(...) that holds data (45000 row). And i want to  create an other table with partitions P_CLIENTS same as the CLIENTS. So i can experiment with.
i noticed a strange behavior.
If i create the P_CLIENTS table with:

```
create table pClients
tablespace TS1
partition by list (pays)(
    Partition PAUST values('Australia') tablespace TS2,
    Partition Pamer values('Chile', 'Brazil', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico') tablespace TS2,
    Partition pafri values('South_africa', 'Cameroun') tablespace TS1,
    Partition peur values('Netherlands', 'Germany', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'France', 'Portugal', 'Switzeland') tablespace TS1,
    Partition poth values (DEFAULT) tablespace TS3
)
as (select * from clients);
```

And i execute a select *  request against it, i  get the following execution plan:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |          | 45000 |  4130K|   195   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION LIST ALL|          | 45000 |  4130K|   195   (1)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     5 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| PCLIENTS | 45000 |  4130K|   195   (1)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     5 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Witch is totaly normal.
But if i use :

```
create table p0Clients (
    noclient  number primary key,
    nom  varchar2(50) not null,
    prenom varchar2(50),
    adresse1 varchar2(100),
    adresse2 varchar2(100),
    codepostal varchar2(10),
    ville varchar2(50),
    pays varchar2(15),
    tel varchar2(20),
    email varchar2(50)
)
tablespace TS1
partition by list (pays)(
    Partition P0AUST values('Australia') tablespace TS2,
    Partition P0amer values('Chile', 'Brazil', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico') tablespace TS2,
    Partition p0afri values('South_africa', 'Cameroun') tablespace TS1,
    Partition p0eur values('Netherlands', 'Germany', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'France', 'Portugal', 'Switzeland') tablespace TS1,
    Partition p0oth values (DEFAULT) tablespace TS3
);

insert into p0Clients select * from Clients;
```

To create the table and execute the same select *  query a get this execution plan whit inexplicable cost and rows  :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |           | 55501 |    12M|  1368   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION LIST ALL|           | 55501 |    12M|  1368   (1)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     5 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| P0CLIENTS | 55501 |    12M|  1368   (1)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     5 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

its a strange behavior is it can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: Just different table statistics gathered by different methods. You can check it using `user_tab_statistics` view.

Comment: shoudn't be a exact copy ?